# Python Check Data for Positive/Negative Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have a homework assignment where I need to read numbers from a .csv file. The file represents a travel reservation system. The first number represents the first, beginning available seats. The rest of the numbers represent the reservations or cancellations depending on if its positive or negative. I've gotten most of it down, but I don't understand how to check the numbers in my list whether they're positive or negative.

Here's my code so far:

```
import csv

fileName = input('Enter file name for transactions: ')
fileOpen = open(fileName, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(fileOpen)

reservations = 0

for row in reader:
    print('Available Start: ', row)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)
```

(The print data is for my own use/reference)

How can I check the list "data" if it contains a positive or negative number? Or is there another way to organize it to check each number?

Also, here's what my .csv file looks like:

```
50
12
-2
5
```

(each number is on its own line)

Comment: Do you know what about if statements? How do you, as a human, determine if a number is negative or positive?

Comment: I've tried using if/else statements... I get this error: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Why are you trying to  compare a list to a number? Do you know how to get a single column of the csv?

Comment: It's not a column (it is but that's not what I want exactly). Here's a picture of my csv file: https://gyazo.com/adc9708966feb09b3269e69c2dbc5587

Comment: You don't  even have a CSV? You just have a text file with one number per line? You do not need `csv.reader`, then

Comment: I need to use csv files because it's my homework assignment. Also, the next assignment uses csv file reading, but this is just getting us familiar with csvs and reading them. It gets more complex later, but for this assignment this is what we need to do.
Also, I was reading, and should I use `any` for checking? How would I apply that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you rather need to know how to read a text file  because you have no "comma separated values"

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f:
        if int(line) > 0;
            print('positive')
```

Even if you did have a CSV, you need to get one value from the row before you compare. And do not use `list()` to consume the entire file.